# How can I change 10182223123 to 10.182.223.123 (IP) in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ip

I trying to do a macro in VBA but I'm having an issue because some IP addresses came without dots and I need to put the dots in the right place independent of the IP.

For example:
10182223123 -> 10.182.223.123

Thanks

Comment: exactly how do you plan to tell between `101.82.223.123` and `10.182.223.123`? Garbage in, garbage out - your inputs are corrupted. Don't try to "correct" the garbage. Fix whatever produced the garbage in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcB points out, you can't distinguish between IPs that have parts with leading 0's, but if you assume the only dropped-zeros are at the start of the string, then you can use this:

```
Sub test1()

  Const IP As String = "10182223123"

  Dim result As String

  result = Format$(IP, "##0\.000\.000\.000")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the address are all for a private network, and therefore start with `10`, and the remaining parts have been encoded with leading zeroes (i.e. a sample address might be `10056123047`) - therefore ensuring that all source strings are 11 characters long - then the following code might work

```
s = "10056123047"
r = Mid(s, 1, 2) & "." & Mid(s, 3, 3) & "." & Mid(s, 6, 3) & "." & Mid(s, 9, 3)
```